# Laptop showing boot menu, with no HDD detected

Tags: laptop, hard-drive

My laptop when turned on, is showing the boot menu and is only detecting the CD drive. But if I reboot, it turns of perfectly well. This problem keeps arising randomly at any moment. Does anybody know what's probably causing it since clearly my HDD is working fine else it wouldnt have turned on later?

Comment: `HDD is working fine else it wouldnt have turned on later` ... dangerous assumption

Answer (score 1):

Consider your [Hard Disk Drive (HDD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive) is randomly failing.  If your HDD is of recent vintage attempt to pull the [S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) data / report from it to determine if the HDD is near end of expected life.  There may also be a log indicating the number and types of HDD failures.  There are many articles which talk about S.M.A.R.T. and predicting HDD failure.  [Here](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2846009/the-5-smart-stats-that-actually-predict-hard-drive-failure.html) is one.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but only when doing a cold start. I did a total backup and sure enough, about 10 days later it crashed and I was unable to get it to run. Put in a new hard drive, restored data and never had the problem again. 
Take it as an early warning sign.